# Whats wrong with my class

Tags: c++, function, class, object, constructor

I don't know why but when i create an object with my class and use the default constructor, when i try to pass the variable named cash to the accessor `user2.setCash(cash)` which purpose is to primary set `cash` equal to `new_cash`, it gives a large value like `1.222256e+461` or something like that. Why does that happen? If i use my overload constructor it works fine.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Bank.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name;
    int id;
    double cash;

bank user2;
cout << "\n\nPlease type your name: ";
getline(cin >> ws, name);
user2.setName(name);
cout << "Enter an id number: ";
cin >> id;
user2.setID(id);
cout << "Enter your cash: ";
cin >> cash;
cout << cash << endl;
user2.setCash(cash);
cout << "\nAlright " << user2.getName() << ", current cash: " << user2.getCash();
cout << "\nChoose how much would you like to Deposit: ";
cin >> cash;
user2.deposit(cash);
cout << "New amount is: " << user2.getCash() << " For user ID: " << user2.getID() << "\n\n";
bank::printStatic();

return 0;
}
```

Bank.h

```
#ifndef BANK_H
#define BANK_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class bank
{
public:
    // Default Constructor
    bank();

    // Overload Constructor
    bank(string, int, double);

    // Destructor
    ~bank();

    // Accessor Functions
    string getName() const;
    int getID() const;
    double getCash() const;

    // Mutator Functions
    void setName(string);
    void setID(int);
    void setCash(double);

    // Functions
    void withdraw(double);
    void deposit(double);
    static void printStatic();

private:
    // Member Variables
    string new_name;
    int new_id;
    double new_cash;

    // Static Member Variables
    static int num_of_accounts;
    static double total_cash;

};

#endif
```

Bank.cpp

```
#include "Bank.h"

// Static Variables
int bank::num_of_accounts = 0;
double bank::total_cash = 0.0;

// Default Constructor
bank::bank()
{
    int new_id = 0;
    double new_cash = 0.0;
    ++num_of_accounts; // New object is created e.g. a person so total accounts must be increased.
}

// Overload Constructor
bank::bank(string name, int id, double cash)
{
    new_name = name;
    new_id = id;
    new_cash = cash;
    ++num_of_accounts; // New object is created e.g. a person so total accounts must be increased.
    total_cash += new_cash; // New object is created e.g. a person so his/hers cash must be added to the total cash of the bank.
}


// Destructor
bank::~bank()
{
    --num_of_accounts; // When Destructor is called to destroy an object (e.g. a person) then the id must be dropped by 1 cause the person e.g. (left).
    total_cash -= new_cash; // And the balance he had to be removed so it is not counted in total cash avaliable in the bank cause he e.g. (left).
}

// Accessor Functions
string bank::getName() const
{
    return new_name;
}

int bank::getID() const
{
    return new_id;
}

double bank::getCash() const
{
    return new_cash;
}

// Mutator Functions
void bank::setName(string name)
{
    new_name = name;
}

void bank::setID(int id)
{
        new_id = id;
}

void bank::setCash(double cash)
{
    cout << new_cash << endl;
    total_cash -= new_cash; // We must remove his prior cash which we holded in the total so we can then use the new value suplied.
    new_cash = cash;
    total_cash += new_cash; // Here we add the new cash (balance) he/she has.
}

void bank::withdraw(double cash)
{
    new_cash -= cash;
    total_cash -= cash;
}

void bank::deposit(double cash)
{
    new_cash += cash;
    total_cash  += cash;
}

void bank::printStatic()
{
    cout << "Total users are: " << num_of_accounts << endl;
    cout << "Total cash in bank is: " << total_cash << endl;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a debugger and do a step-by-step debugging?

Comment: Please try reducing your code down to a [minimal but still complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.  During that exercise, you are most likely to find the error yourself and if not, you'll have a better chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Be clear about what the code does and what you want it to do.  "[I]t gives a large value like 1.222256e+461 or something like that" leaves room for increased clarity.

Comment: That's way to much code to point out for the particular problem. Be clear! Voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize all primitive type members in the constructor.

Otherwise you get indeterminate values

Also, the non-default constructor is buggy:

```
// Default Constructor
bank::bank()
{
    int new_id = 0; 
    double new_cash = 0.0;
 ....
```

^ sets values of local variables, not the member variables

---

I'd suggest to use the initilization lists:

```
// Default Constructor
bank::bank() : new_name(), new_id(0), new_cash(0.0)
{
    ++num_of_accounts;
}

// Overload Constructor
bank::bank(string name, int id, double cash)
    : new_name(name), new_id(id), new_cash(cash)
{
    ++num_of_accounts;
    total_cash += new_cash;
}
```

You could also combine the two:

```
bank::bank(string name = "", int id = 0, double cash = 0.0)
    : new_name(name), new_id(id), new_cash(cash)
{
    ++num_of_accounts;
    total_cash += new_cash;
}
```

Comment: Oh so my friend you mean i need to put in the default constructor the total_cash variable too?

Comment: That. And there's a bug in the other ctor. Updating

Comment: Thanks my friend i will try it but something weird cause i was watching this tutorial and if you see around the 17:40 part he dosnt't put it in his default constructor but his program still works. link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7u7ti-S69uY&index=24&list=PL318A5EB91569E29A

Comment: @Johnson: No. There's only that one error of you inadvertently defining two local variables in the default ctor, instead of assigning the members.

Comment: @Johnson Youtube sucks. At least here, seriously!

Comment: Oh yea i found that out i accidentally in the default put declared 2 variables again

Comment: Cheers! You figured this part. Good luck with the rest of the assignment

Comment: sehe i still do not understand this part. you say "You need to initialize all primitive type members in the constructor." so do i just put the total_cash in the default constructor and leave it like that? cause i have already set it to 0.0 above.

Comment: @Johnson: It's a static member, and thus the ctor is far too late to initialize it. You did it right. (Well, actually you only needed the definition in the implementation file. You could leave off the initializer and rely on zero-initialization of static data.)

Answer (score -1):

In your default constructor, you're declaring local variables with the same names as the member variables. Then you're setting these local variables instead of assigning the members. Get rid of the type declarations so they're normal assignments.

```
bank::bank()
{
    new_id = 0;
    new_cash = 0.0;
    ++num_of_accounts; // New object is created e.g. a person so total accounts must be increased.
}
```

Comment: Thanks my friend i thought that strings are always null if not initialiazed (thats what a guy in a youtube tutorial series said) so he said there is no need to initialiaze it to null or empty.

Comment: You don't actually need to initialize new_name (as non-primitives get default constructed in the order or member declaration anyways). Also, `new_name = "";` is assignment, not initialization.

Comment: @sehe: All members are default-initialized if not specifically initialized some other way. That might mean uninitialized for some types though. Might want to expand the comment...

Comment: @Deduplicator Yup. Which is why I chose my words carefully. There's a balance to be found how much information to put in a comment. You aptly complemented that :)

Comment: @Deduplicator May be you should consider participating at the [c++ lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) chat room occasionally.